# PHP SELECT Statement group by clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to order my results by either ASC or DESC by using the following select statement.

```
$query = "SELECT filmcode, FilmName, Genre FROM film WHERE Genre = '".$genre_value."' ORDER by '".$order_value."' ASC";
```

The table is loading correctly however attributes are not ordered ASC, can someone help me find what is wrong with the select statement?

Comment: `ASC` is the default, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The statement doesn't order the records correctly because the column name was wrapped with single quotes. Remove the quotes and it will surely work:

```
$query = "SELECT filmcode, FilmName, Genre FROM film WHERE Genre = '$genre_value' ORDER by $order_value ASC";
```

If `$order_value` is a column name, it can be escape using backtick if it happens to be a reserved keyword. Column names and table names are identifier. Single quotes makes identifier a string literal causing the order by clause to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: If I wanted to put a variable called $radio which is either = to ASC or DESC. Would the following statement work fine - $query = "SELECT filmcode, FilmName, Genre FROM film WHERE Genre = '".$genre_value."' ORDER by ".$order_value." ".$varible." ";

Comment: Yes you can. By the way you can omit the concatenation and put the variable directly on the statement to avoid confusion or syntax error.